# Why does this QuickSort code fail using Hoare's partition?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

```
class QuickSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 8, 3, 5, 1, 34, 6, 35, 5, 23, 2, 7 };
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int x : arr)
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    System.out.println();
    qSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    for (int x : arr)
        System.out.print(x + " ");

}

static int partition(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    int pivot = arr[h];
    int i = l - 1, j = h + 1;
    while (true) {
        do {
            i++;
        } while (arr[i] < pivot);
        do {
            j--;
        } while (arr[j] > pivot);
        if (i >= j)
            return j;
        swap(i,j,arr);
    }
}

static void qSort(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int p = partition(arr, l, h);
        qSort(arr, l, p);
        qSort(arr, p + 1, h);
    }
}}
```

It works when I choose the pivot as arr[l] , however gives stackoverflow error because if recursion when pivot is chosen as arr[h].
Does the choice of pivot matter? And if at all it matters, could you please tell why?

Answer (score 0):

Hoare partition scheme will not work if arr[h] is chosen as the pivot. It will work for any other element of arr[l] to arr[h-1]. The failure occurs when the size is reduced to 2 elements, h = l+1, and a[l] < a[h]. The loop exits with i == h and j == h, and returns h. Then it calls itself again, with the same values for l and h (h == l+1), resulting in infinite recursion stopped only by a stack overflow exception.

Typcially for Hoare partition scheme arr[(l+h)/2] is chosen as the pivot. This relies on the divide by 2 to round down to l when h = l+1.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have finally understood it :D